# Angular 2 Are BehaviorSubjects the correct way to handle changeable items?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm using BehaviourSubjects in Angular-Services to handle items which are used of many components at the same time.

But if I have changeable items (like the Herosets in my advanced Hero Tour App), the concept doesn't work as expected.

My-Heroset-App: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3gouf

If the user opens a Set, the Overview-Page sets the specific items to the Subject. If the user opens another set, he can see the old set until the new Set is resolved.

I solved this issue but it look's like a workaround.

```
ngOnDestroy() { this.setHeroes(null); this.subscription.unsubscribe(); }
```

A resolver would solve this issue as well but I don't think it's a good way for me.

Is there a better way to handle this? Is there another concept?

Thank

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BehaviorSubjects are bad for this (and only good for very rare cases). You can simply replace it with Observable.of(data) in this case, as in a real world app you'd likely get the data from an API as an observable.

Edit: Some code. Sorry I'm on tablet so stackblitz doesn't quite work and writing code is a bit painful. Hope you get the idea from this :)

Service:

```
private heroSets = [ [{id:1}], [{id:2}] ]; 
getHeroSet (index:number):Observable<Hero> { 
   return Observable.of(this.heroSets[index]); 
   // Simulated api call. In real world, 
   // usually return a call to HttpClient ie. this.http.get(...),
   // and you won't need to change any other code.
}
```

Component:

```
heros$:Observable<Hero>;
chooseHeroSet(index:number) { 
   this.heros$ = this.service.getHeroSet(index);
}
```

Tpl:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of (heros$ | async)">{{hero.id}}</div>
```

Comment: Can you give a small example how to use it in my app? If I try to find something about observable services I stumble over BehaviorSubjects

Comment: Thank, but how can I avoid that I call the http request multiple times? This is what the behaviorSubject do for me now.

Comment: One way is Subject. It's an observer+observable like a BSubject, but without an internal state so it doesn't have a start value or remember what it had last. Then there's share (which subjects use internally): https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html and more advanced state management tools like NGRX. But! There really is no need if you design the app smart. Like if you need to do several things with one set of data, you can just use tap(). Subscribe only in one smart component, pass the data down to dumb children (using share() if you want to pass it as an observable), etc.

Comment: So let's say you have multiple async pipes touching the observable in my example, avoding multiple api calls is as easy as this.heros$ = this.service.getHeroSet(index).pipe(share());

Comment: And adding side-effects: this.heros$ = this.service.getHeroSet(index).pipe(share(), tap(console.log));

Comment: Can you please make a small example? I don't really understand the concept. Maybe u can use my stackblitz example? (Btw. I dont use Async, it's just from the hero-example)